# Using functions from delegate in SwiftUIView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Quick question for anyone feeling up for helping a noob.
So I have a protocol in my main class that has a function that I'd like to access from a UIView. This works for other view controllers.  However, in my prepare function, I try this:

```
        if let destination = segue.destination as? SwiftUIView {
            destination.delegate = self
    }
```

But I get, "Cast from 'UIViewController' to unrelated type 'SwiftUIView' always fails"
and "Cannot assign to property: 'destination' is a 'let' constant".

This is my whole prepare function:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.destination is ClientView
    {
        let vc = segue.destination as? ClientView
        vc?.username = thetitle;
    }
    if let destination = segue.destination as? CreateClientView {
            destination.delegate = self
    }
    if let destination = segue.destination as? SwiftUIView {
            destination.delegate = self
    }
}
```

and it works in the CreateClientView.  But not for my SwiftUIView.  Any idea how to fix this?  I am accessing the function in SwiftUIView the same way I do in CreateClientView. Thanks everybody.

SwiftUIView is just type View and looks like this (abridged):

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
@State var username: String = ""
@State var address: String = "";
@State var notificationsEnabled: Bool = false
@State var note: String = "";
var delegate:ClientDelegate?;
```

and SwiftUIView is a child of another view which looks like this:

```
class CreateClientView: UIViewController {
let contentView = UIHostingController(rootView: SwiftUIView());

var delegate:ClientDelegate?;
var mainView : ViewController?;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addChild(contentView);
    view.addSubview(contentView.view);
    setupConstraints()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `SwiftUIView` ? can you show the code?

Comment: @AbhishekHarsha yes, sorry, i have included that in my post. See edit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, you're trying to cast a SwiftUI `view` into a `ViewController`. which you cant.

For a quick fix to your problem you can try this

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.destination is ClientView
    {
        let vc = segue.destination as? ClientView
        vc?.username = thetitle;
    }
    if let destination = segue.destination as? CreateClientView {
            destination.delegate = self
    }
    if let destination = segue.destination as? CreateClientView {
            destination.delegate = self
    }
}

class CreateClientView: UIViewController, SwiftUIViewDelegate  {
let contentView = UIHostingController(rootView: SwiftUIView(delegate: self));

var delegate:ClientDelegate?;
var mainView : ViewController?;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addChild(contentView);
    view.addSubview(contentView.view);
    setupConstraints()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

// MARK: SwiftUIViewDelegate
// call `ClientDelegate` here whereever `SwiftUIViewDelegate` methods are implemeted
}

```
protocol SwiftUIViewDelegate {...}

struct SwiftUIView {
 let delegate:  SwiftUIViewDelegate 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time sir. On `let contentView = UIHostingController(rootView: SwiftUIView(delegate: self));`
I am getting "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"
Any idea?

Comment: `struct SwiftUIView {
 let delegate:  SwiftUIViewDelegate 

init(delegate: SwiftUIViewDelegate) {
self.delegate = delegate
}
}`

Comment: can you try this?